# How to print XPath search?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an XML file with Nokogiri:

```
 require 'nokogiri'
 require 'open-uri'

  @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?sportType=E%20Sports&contest=no'))
  @doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']")
  print @doc.text
```

which works and prints all the events that contain "LOL" in the "league" attribute, but when I create a block, it runs but prints nothing:

```
@doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']").each do |league_element|
   puts "\n"+league_element.xpath('league').text
end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Nokogiri gem. The docs are for REXML.      `<main>': uninitialized constant XPath (NameError)

Comment: ah, could have seen that actually (: can you puts all `league_element`s (without the inner `.xpath`) and see an expected result? If not, my guess is that you iterate over a single item and need to do something like `@doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']")[0].each do ...`

Comment: `@doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']").each do |league_element|
  puts "\n"+league_element
end`   Doesn't return anything. Adding [0] before each gives undefined method for "each"?

Comment: `@doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']")` `puts(@doc.xpath("//league").text)`  works and prints them, wonder why it doesn't work in the block?

Comment: My goal was to iterate though each event that contained LOL and print that, along with other attributes of the event. But I couldn't get it to print the name of the league and the new line.

Comment: Similar to this, https://coderwall.com/p/03r98q/using-the-nokogiri-gem-to-parse-nested-xml-data-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?sportType=E%20Sports&contest=no'))
events = @doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']")
puts @doc.children
```

[`.children`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#children-instance_method) "returns a new NodeSet containing all the children of all the nodes in the NodeSet." you can keep filtering node names and values using `children.xpath()`

For example:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?sportType=E%20Sports&contest=no'))
events = @doc.xpath("//event[@league='*LOL*']")
puts @doc.children.xpath('//league').text

=> LOL Cham Kor
=> LOL Cham Kor
=> ....
```

Or

```
@doc.children.each do |item|
  puts item.xpath('//league')
end
```

Comment: `puts @doc.children.xpath('//league')` works perfectly and lists every name of the league for the events, but when I do `@doc.children.each do |item|
  puts "League: #{item.xpath('//league')}"
end` I get three groups of a bunch of "LOL Cham Kor"